# Woocommerce: Reading a JSON feed sent to REST API?

Tags: php, rest, woocommerce

I have a JSON feed running from a third party accounting package to a WooCommerce website to update products.

Is it possible to write a separate php script to pick up the JSON feed which is sending to the WooCommerce API and to then display it?

Comment: Is it possible to write a separate php script to pick up the JSON feed which is sending to the WooCommerce API and to then display it? - Yes.